# Проблема с OwlCarousel

Tags: javascript, html, css

Проблема состоит в том, что Карусель попросту не работает. Все настроено и подключено, как положено, но результата 0. Уже пытался разобраться всевозможными методами, но безрезультатно. Прошу помочь мне с этой проблемой.

```
    <div class="videos">
    <div class="information col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <p style="color: #51555b;">Creative Agency</p>
        <h1>We Make Dreams</h1>
        <p style="color: #757c86;">Beautiful interfaces and creative solutions</p>
        <div class="buttons">
            <a href="#" class="read_more">Read More</a>
            <a href="#" class="portfolio_button">Portfolio</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="film col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">              
            <div class="item"><img src="js/owl/demos/assets/fullimage1.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="js/owl/demos/assets/fullimage2.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="js/owl/demos/assets/fullimage3.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/owl/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<script>

(function($){
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

      navigation : true, // Show next and prev buttons
      slideSpeed : 300,
      paginationSpeed : 400,
      singleItem: true

  });

});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Ваш код (минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример) должен быть в вопросе. Иначе это дистанционная отладка, коей тут не занимаются

Comment: Извиняюсь, не знал просто. Код предоставил

Comment: Подключены ли у вас стили для owl-carousel?